# AuraHandledException message: extra word ("Exception") at beginning of message

Tags: aura, exception

I am working on a component+Apex class.

I need to throw an error message via AuraHandledException.

Everything seems to be working fine except for the error message itself: it's showing up with an extra word ("Exception") at the beginning of the message!

[image]

I really do not know what to do. That extra "Exception" must be coming from some default value that I do not recognise. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code for reference.

My Apex code is the following:

```
      if(acc.Login_Email__c != null || acc.Login_Email__c != ''){
        List <Account> loginEmail = [SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE Login_Email__c =: acc.Login_Email__c];
            if(loginEmail.size()>0){
                AuraHandledException e = new AuraHandledException('A customer with this email address already exists');
                e.setMessage('A customer with this email address already exists');
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

and my JavaScript controller has the following:

else if(state === 'ERROR'){

```
        var errors = action.getError()[0].message;
        var errorsMsg = [];
        errorsMsg.push(errors);
        cmp.set("v.errors", errorsMsg);
        helper.hideSpinner(cmp);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

.cls

```
throw new AuraHandledException('A customer with this email address already exists');
```

.js controller

```
else if (state === 'ERROR') {
   var errors = response.getError();
   if(errors) {
      if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
         var errorsMsg = [];
         errorsMsg.push(errors[0].message);
         cmp.set("v.errors", errorsMsg);
         helper.hideSpinner(cmp);

         console.log(errors[0].message);
      }
   }else {
      console.log("Unknown error");
   }
}
```

check [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2017/09/error-handling-best-practices-lightning-apex.html) out

To be more accurate I tried testing it like so and it worked fine:

```
else if (state === 'ERROR') {
   var errors = response.getError();
   if(errors) {
      if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
         var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
         resultsToast.setParams({
             "type":"error",
             "title": errors[0].message,
             "message": errors                        
         });
         resultsToast.fire();

         console.log(errors[0].message);
      }
   }else {
      console.log("Unknown error");
   }
}
```

I am not sure how you handle the code in html to display the error.